# How to Apply a Uniform Load to a Laminate Plate in FEM

Tags: finite-element, matlab

As the title says, I'm trying to make my code include a uniform pressure/force to the surface of a plate for analysis.

**Structural/Element Modeling**

I am modeling a 2D 9 node Mindlin plate that has a clamped boundary condition on one side. It is 0.2 [m] by 0.2 [m]. Currently, I am using 6x6 elements. The plate has 6 layers, consisting of, in order from top to bottom,

- 0.1  [mm] thick piezoelectric layer at a 0 degree angle
- 0.25 [mm] thick composite material layer at a -45 degree angle
- 0.25 [mm] thick composite material layer at a  45 degree angle
- 0.25 [mm] thick composite material layer at a  45 degree angle
- 0.25 [mm] thick composite material layer at a -45 degree angle
- 0.1  [mm] thick piezoelectric layer at a 0 degree angle

**The Problem**

As far as calculating the electric load, I am 100% sure that it is correct. Same with calculating the various effects of the different orientations of the plates. The code works perfectly fine when I only include the electrical load, so that's not the problem.

After some tinkering and some astute remarks, I have realized that the issue is not with the construction of the Force Matrix, but rather, the way I implemented the uniform load. I had originally just made a Force Matrix and multiplied the entire thing with the load I wanted to apply. This was a fundamental flaw. So I started my studies again and found that the force matrix must be calculated as shown in the image.

[image: Force Vector equation]

Since in my case, the fz was a constant, I integrated the nine-node shape functions w.r.t to the area and got the following:

```
H1 =  (1/4) * (1 - xi) * (1 - eta) * xi * eta --> 1/9
H2 = -(1/4) * (1 + xi) * (1 - eta) * xi * eta --> 1/9
H3 =  (1/4) * (1 + xi) * (1 + eta) * xi * eta --> 1/9
H4 = -(1/4) * (1 - xi) * (1 + eta) * xi * eta --> 1/9
H5 = -(1/2) * (1 - xi^2) * (1 - eta) * eta    --> 4/9
H6 =  (1/2) * (1 + xi) * (1 - eta^2) * xi     --> 4/9
H7 =  (1/2) * (1 - xi^2) * (1 + eta) * eta    --> 4/9
H8 = -(1/2) * (1 - xi) * (1 - eta^2) * xi     --> 4/9
H9 =  (1 - xi^2) * (1 - eta^2)                --> 16/9
```

**The Code I Implemented**

So, instead of making my Force Vector with the code:

```
fef = [ H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 ] * P;

for i = 1:length(nodes)

    Fe(i,1) = 0;
    Fe(i+num_node_ele,1) = 0;
    Fe(i+num_node_ele*2,1) = 0;
    Fe(i+num_node_ele*3,1) = 0;
    Fe(i+(num_node_ele*4),1) = fef(i);

end

f = f + Fe * (detjacob);
```

I changed it by making P into a matrix like so:

```
a = 1/9;
b = 4/9;
c = 16/9;

dist_load = P * [ a a a a b b b b c ];

fef = H .* dist_load;
% the rest is identical
```

Doing so gives me deflections of reasonable ranges and the deflection converges as I increase the number of elements. So now, I must ask, did I do this correctly? Is there something I missed?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If the displacement vector is all zero, my guess is that this is just a basic programming error. What do you get when you print Fg for a one-element model? The nd vector of indices looks odd to me.

Comment: Hi! You always seem to help me out with my FEM debugging and I truly appreciate it! Thank you.

So first, your advice was well taken, and the loading of the initial vector was a bit wonky. So I fixed that and added a rather redundant and length section at the end for global assembly. Also, instead of doing 2 nested for loops for the Gauss Points, I just did a single for loop of 4, thus simplifying things.

However, now the problem is the opposite: the smallest force deforms the plate too much! And to top it off, increasing the number of elements increases the load! (1/2)

Comment: I have checked the Jacobians and they are diagonal and everything else seems to be in place. I just don't know what the issue is. Also, for the sake of clarity, the matrix is ordered so that it first lists all the x-directional force for the all nodes, then the y-directional, then the x-directional angular, then the y-directional angular, then finally all the z-directional load. Thus, the Fg matrix is all 0 until the end. Any advice is appreciated! (2/2)

Comment: Sorry, You haven't replied yet, but I just had a quick question: Is there some factor that I should multiply the force P with? It is a uniform load and in one of my previous questions, that was a problem I had with a 2D plate and a uniform force was applied along the length of the plate and I had to multiply it with Lx/(2*num_ele_x).

Comment: The sum of the nine nodal forces obviously should equal P \* Area. And the nodal forces should be symmetric wrt to axes through the element center. When debugging, I *always* add an area( or volume) calculation to my integration loop as a simple test. Those tests should be enough to find the problem. There is no need to consider more than a single element while debugging.

Comment: "problem I had with a 2D plate and a uniform force was applied along the length of the plate and I had to multiply it with Lx/(2*num_ele_x)". This sounds like a fundamental error in your implementation of consistent nodal loads. I suggest you edit your question to show the equations you are using to calculate the loads. You can remove all the extraneous information about the plate being laminated and also the information about the size, boundary conditions, etc, of the problem you ultimately would like to solve.

Comment: I did as you said and I changed my question to focus more on the crux of the issue, which is the way I made my Force Matrix. I also entailed how I think I solved the issue. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Your basic equation is correct but your implementation doesn't follow from that equation. That "scaling" of the pressure makes no sense to me; I essentially said that in my previous comment. I believe your integrals of the shape functions are correct if your element is size 2 x 2. I put this in the form of a short answer which will hopefully make this clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a plate element lying in the x-y plane, the consistent nodal loads corresponding to a pressure load on the
face are given by

$$ f_i = \int_{A_e} N_i P(x,y) dx dy $$

where $N_i$ is the shape function at the ith node and $P$ is the pressure. Of course, if $P$ is constant, as it is in your
case, it can  be moved outside the integral so the nodal loads are simply the integral of the shape functions multiplied
by the pressure

$$ f_i = P\int_{A_e} N_i dx dy $$

The only remaining step is to sum these elemental load components into the appropriate locations in the global load vector.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Hello! Sorry, but I don't think I was clear enough. I apologize.

In my new implementation of code, the load_dist 'scaling' is simply stating the integrals of the shape functions in a matrix and multiplying it all with the applied load P.